# nesting with namedtuple

Tags: python, namedtuple

I'm having trouble getting my data in the form that I'd like in python.

Basically I have a program that reads in binary data and provides functions for plotting and analysis on said data.

My data has main headings and then subheadings that could be any number of varied datatypes.

I'd like to be able to access my data like for example:

```
>>> a = myDatafile.readit()
>>> a.elements.hydrogen.distributionfunction
(a big array)
>>> a.elements.hydrogen.mass
1
>>> a.elements.carbon.mass
12
```

but I don't know the names of the atoms until runtime.

I've tried using namedtuple, for example after I've read in all the atom names:

```
self.elements = namedtuple('elements',elementlist)
```

Where elementlist is a list of strings for example ('hydrogen','carbon'). But the problem is I can't nest these using for example:

```
for i in range(0,self.nelements):
    self.elements[i] = namedtuple('details',['ux','uy','uz','mass','distributionfunction'])
```

and then be able to access the values through for example

```
self.elements.electron.distributionfunction.
```

Maybe I'm doing this completely wrong. I'm fairly inexperienced with python. I know this would be easy to do if I wasn't bothered about naming the variables dynamically.

I hope I've made myself clear with what I'm trying to achieve!

Comment: Can you please show us the sample data?

Comment: @abhijit
It's fairly complicated and is read in as binary data.

The number of chemical elements is variable from file to file but each element has:

'a name (string)
mass (double precision)
charge (double precision)
3d velocity grid (3 * n * double precision)
phasespace grid (n^6 * double precision)'

I have a class which reads the binary and reads it into variables, but I'm having trouble creating the data structure that can be accessed in the way that I have described.

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing your data, we can only give a generic solution.

Considering the first two lines contains the headings and Sub-Heading reading it somehow you determined the hierarchy. All you have to do is to create an hierarchical dictionary.

For example, extending your example

```
data.elements.hydrogen.distributionfunction
data.elements.nitrogen.xyzfunction
data.elements.nitrogen.distributionfunction
data.compound.water.distributionfunction
data.compound.hcl.xyzfunction
```

So we have to create a dictionary as such

```
{'data':{'elements':{'hydrogen':{'distributionfunction':<something>}
                     'nitrogen':{'xyzfunction':<something>,
                           'distributionfunction':<something>}
                }
       compound:{'water':{'distributionfunction':<something>}
                 'hcl':{'xyzfunction':<something>}
                }
       }
 }
```

how you will populate the dictionary depends on the data which is difficult to say now.
But the keys to the dictionary you should populate from the headers, and somehow you have to map the data to the respective value in the empty slot's of the dictionary.

Once the map is populated, you can access it as

```
 yourDict['data']['compound']['hcl']['xyzfunction']
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! So will this work for any datatype? for example if some fields are strings and some fields are numpy arrays? So could i do 'distributionfunction':self.dist1 where self.dist1 is a 3d numpy array?

Once again thanks! I fully appreciate your time!

Comment: As you see in the example I have only intended keys to be strings (which are hash-able). As long as keys are hashable, you can store anything in the value, any data types, functions, objects, what ever on earth you intend.

Answer (score 3):

If your element name are dynamic and obtained from the data at runtime, you can assign them to a dict and access like this

```
elements['hydrogen'].mass
```

but if you want dotted notation you can create attributes at run time e.g.

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Elements(object):
    def add_element(self, elementname, element):
        setattr(self, elementname, element)

Element = namedtuple('Element', ['ux','uy','uz','mass','distributionfunction'])

elements = Elements()
for data in [('hydrogen',1,1,1,1,1), ('helium',2,2,2,2,2), ('carbon',3,3,3,3,3)]:
    elementname = data[0]
    element = Element._make(data[1:])
    elements.add_element(elementname, element)

print elements.hydrogen.mass
print elements.carbon.distributionfunction
```

Here I am assuming the data you have, but with data in any other format you can do similar tricks

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method for recursively creating namedtuples from nested data.

```
from collections import Mapping, namedtuple


def namedtuplify(mapping, name='NT'):  # thank you https://gist.github.com/hangtwenty/5960435
    """ Convert mappings to namedtuples recursively. """
    if isinstance(mapping, Mapping):
        for key, value in list(mapping.items()):
            mapping[key] = namedtuplify(value)
        return namedtuple_wrapper(name, **mapping)
    elif isinstance(mapping, list):
        return [namedtuplify(item) for item in mapping]
    return mapping

def namedtuple_wrapper(name, **kwargs):
    wrap = namedtuple(name, kwargs)
    return wrap(**kwargs)


stuff = {'data': {'elements': {'hydrogen': {'distributionfunction': 'foo'}, 
  'nitrogen': {'xyzfunction': 'bar', 
    'distributionfunction': 'baz'}
  },
  'compound': {'water': {'distributionfunction': 'lorem'}, 
    'hcl': {'xyzfunction': 'ipsum'}}}
 }

example = namedtuplify(stuff)

example.data.elements.hydrogen.distributionfunction  # 'foo'
```

Comment: This is great. The only problem is that it won't serialise with pickle as pickle can't keep track of the structure. I've done an enhanced version which does. I'll post below.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with nested json but needed to be able to serialise the output with pickle which doesn't like you creating objects on the fly.

I've taken @bren's answer and enhanced it so that the resulting structure will be serialisable with pickle. You have to save references to each of the structures you create to globals so that pickle can keep tabs on them.

```
##############################################
class Json2Struct:
    '''
    Convert mappings to nested namedtuples

    Usage:
        jStruct = Json2Struct('JS').json2Struct(json)
    '''
##############################################

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.namePrefix = name
        self.nameSuffix = 0


    def json2Struct(self, jsonObj):  # thank you https://gist.github.com/hangtwenty/5960435
        """ 
        Convert mappings to namedtuples recursively. 
        """
        if isinstance(jsonObj, Mapping):
            for key, value in list(jsonObj.items()):
                jsonObj[key] = self.json2Struct(value)
            return self.namedtuple_wrapper(**jsonObj)
        elif isinstance(jsonObj, list):
            return [self.json2Struct(item) for item in jsonObj]
        return jsonObj


    def namedtuple_wrapper(self, **kwargs):
        self.nameSuffix += 1
        name = self.namePrefix + str(self.nameSuffix)

        Jstruct = namedtuple(name, kwargs)
        globals()[name] = Jstruct

        return Jstruct(**kwargs)
```

The example below should work as follows and also be serialisable:

```
stuff = {'data': {'elements': {'hydrogen': {'distributionfunction': 'foo'}, 
  'nitrogen': {'xyzfunction': 'bar', 
    'distributionfunction': 'baz'}
  },
  'compound': {'water': {'distributionfunction': 'lorem'}, 
    'hcl': {'xyzfunction': 'ipsum'}}}
 }

example = Json2Struct('JS').json2Struct(stuff)

example.data.elements.hydrogen.distributionfunction  # 'foo'
```